# R - subset rows based on column names (in a vector) and specific values in those columns

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, dplyr, subset

This is how my `df` looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(WoS = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), Scopus = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), Dim = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Lens = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L))
```

or:

```
| WoS| Scopus| Dim| Lens| # (+ various other columns)
|---:|------:|---:|----:|
|   1|      1|  NA|   NA|
|  NA|      1|  NA|   NA|
|   1|      1|   1|   NA|
|  NA|      1|   1|    1|
|   1|     NA|   1|   NA|
|  NA|     NA|   1|    1|

# (+ hundreds of other rows in which 1 and NAs are distributed among these four columns)
```

I want to subset `df` based on a vector in which column names are stored; the values of at least one of these columns should equal `1`.

The other columns *not* mentioned in `vec` should be `NA`.

**Example:**

Say that I have a vector `vec <- c("WoS", "Scopus")`.

Then I want to select all rows where `df$WoS = 1` OR `df$Scopus = 1`, and where `is.na(df$Dim)` and `is.na(df$Lens)`:

```
| WoS| Scopus| Dim| Lens| # (+ keep all other columns ...)
|---:|------:|---:|----:|
|   1|      1|  NA|   NA|
|  NA|      1|  NA|   NA|
|   1|     NA|  NA|   NA|
|  NA|      1|  NA|   NA|
|   1|      1|  NA|   NA|
```

How to do it in the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can store the column names into vectors, and then apply `filter` for different conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

target1 <- c("WoS", "Scopus")
target2 <- c("Dim", "Lens")

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(rowSums(select(., all_of(target1)), na.rm = TRUE) <= 2) %>%
  filter(across(all_of(target2), .fns = is.na))
df2
#   WoS Scopus Dim Lens
# 1   1      1  NA   NA
# 2  NA      1  NA   NA
```

If you don't like to use `rowSums` as the values in some columns may not be strictly one, we can change to the following, using `filter` and `if_any`.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(if_any(all_of(target1), .fns = function(x) x == 1)) %>%
  filter(across(all_of(target2), .fns = is.na))
df2
#   WoS Scopus Dim Lens
# 1   1      1  NA   NA
# 2  NA      1  NA   NA
```

We can also change the `across` in the second `filter` function to `if_all`.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(if_any(all_of(target1), .fns = function(x) x == 1)) %>%
  filter(if_all(all_of(target2), .fns = is.na))
df2
#   WoS Scopus Dim Lens
# 1   1      1  NA   NA
# 2  NA      1  NA   NA
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I find it especially wonderful that you integrated a solution with the brand-new `if_any` and `if_all`-functions. :-) Thanks a lot!